# Web scraping: How to test if the root tag has a particular CSS class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've got a soup object with these contents:

```
<tr class="x--player-is-starter">
<td class="pos" style="display: none; height: 62px;">10</td>
<td class="name" style="display: none; height: 62px;">
<a class="player-profile-link" href="/eurocupwomen/18-19/player/Maria-Conde" target="_blank"> Maria Conde</a>
</td>
<td class="min" style="height: 62px;">29:37</td>
<td class="pts" style="height: 62px;">13</td>
<td class="field-goals" style="height: 62px;">
<span class="made-all">4/8</span>
<span class="percent">50%</span>
</td>
<td class="field-goals-2p" style="height: 62px;">
<span class="made-all">1/2</span>
<span class="percent">50%</span>
</td>
<td class="field-goals-3p" style="height: 62px;">
<span class="made-all">3/6</span>
<span class="percent">50%</span>
</td>
<td class="free-throw" style="height: 62px;">
<span class="made-all">2/4</span>
<span class="percent">50%</span>
</td>
<td class="reb-offence" style="height: 62px;">2</td>
<td class="reb-defence" style="height: 62px;">0</td>
<td class="reb-total" style="height: 62px;">2</td>
<td class="assists" style="height: 62px;">3</td>
<td class="personal-fouls" style="height: 62px;">0</td>
<td class="turnovers" style="height: 62px;">1</td>
<td class="steals" style="height: 62px;">3</td>
<td class="block-shots" style="height: 62px;">0</td>
<td class="plus-minus" style="height: 62px;">2</td>
<td class="efficiency" style="height: 62px;">14</td>
</tr>
```

I want to know how to know if the tag "tr" has the CSS `class = "x--player-is-starter"`.

If this object that contains the above `tr` is called `row`, for example, I have tried using `row.find("tr", class_="x--player-is-starter")`, but I always get "None" as a result.

So, how can I know if a `"tr"` tag has the CSS class that I am trying to find? Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit I:**

I have no problem to get the contents that are inside the "tr" tag, but I want to know if that tag "tr" has the CSS `class = "x--player-is-starter"`.

I would like to get a `True` or `False`, if it's possible, for example:

`<tr class = "x--player-is-starter">` returns `True` and `<tr class = "">` returns `False`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep it more general and use a css tag selector then test each class

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
results = [(i.get('class'), True) if i.get('class')[0] == "x--player-is-starter" else (i.get('class'), False) for i in soup.select('tr')]
print(results)
```